# Find same names in CSV files. C++

Tags: c++, csv

I'm trying to write a program that will compare two or more CSV files and find the same name names and print them out if there are two or more of them. Each name will only appear once in one file.

Here is what a typical file looks like.

```
Name,E-mail,Student Level,Major
John Doe, jdoe@something.com, Freshman, CS
Jane Doe, janed@something.com, Freshman, CS
....
```

So if either of those name are in two or more file, the program should print out their name and the number total number of times their name shows up in the file.

I have done this much so far. I have gotten it to print out just the names from one file. Don't know what to do next. Here is the code for that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define buffer 1024

int main(){
    FILE *fp;
    char temp[buffer], *fn, *ln;
    char *first[buffer], *last[buffer];
    int line_count = 0;
    fp = fopen("students.csv", "r");

    while( (fgets(temp, buffer, fp) != NULL) )
    {
            first[line_count] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)* buffer);
            last[line_count] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * buffer);

            ln = strtok(temp,",");
            fn = strtok(NULL,",");
            strcpy(first[line_count], fn);
            strcpy(last[line_count], ln);
            line_count++;
    }

    while(line_count--)
    {
            printf("Name : %s %s\n", first[line_count], last[line_count]);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm new to C++(hence me writing the code in C), so if someone could point me in the right direction. That would be great. Thank you.

Comment: There are actually two problems to solve here: Parsing the CSV file and finding the duplicates in the resulting data. Which one do you have problems with and what are the problems?

Comment: By the way, that code looks like pure C, not like C++. malloc instead of new, arrays instead of STL containers, char[] instead of std::string, printf instead of cout.

Comment: Well I have parsed one of the files and was able to get the names into arrays. So I guess the problem is, how to compare the name to see if its in the other file as well.

And yes, this is C, I wrote on the bottom that I am new to C++, hence using C, since I am more comfortable in that.

Answer (score 1):

As you read each name from the CSV input files, you should try to insert it to a `std::set<std::string>` (you'll need to `#include <set>` and `#include <string>`.  If that fails due to the key already being present, you know the name is one of your outputs.

Comment: +1, Note for OP: [std::set<>::insert()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert) just skips the actual insert (and return an iterator/bool pair with the bool false) if the item already existed. This can be a time-saver, as you don't have to do a find/insert combo. just insert and check the result `p.second`. if it is false, then you have encountered a duplicate. Furthermore, if you have a C++11 toolchain, `std::unordered_set<>` may be a better fit for you, as it doesn't appear you care about order; just *existence*. It also has better performance (usually).

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems you are just looking for a method rather than the code (you already like writing C). Then here is a "method" that uses what you already have.

Since you have already successfully parsed one file just repeat the process for the other file (copy, paste, change a few name, etc).

Then you will have two sets of arrays, say first1, first2, last1, last2. Now you can just step though them to find any matches (sudo code below).

```
for each line in first1 and last2
  look for match in first2 and last2
  log/print the matches
```

Now as far as how you are going about it I would definitely recommend more C++ ish code. You can take advantage of std::string and std::vector functionality to make the code simpler.